# How to write an if statement regarding if an event happened in a certain timeframe?

Tags: python

I'm working on a notification system that lets students know when they accumulate ten or more points.  I'm working with a couple if statements - one that checks if points >= 10, and one that checks if that student already received a notification this semester for ten or more points.  If they have not already received a notification for this, then one is sent out.  The issue I am running into is the scenario where a student had ten points and received a notification, appealed some points and got a few removed (so they are back under ten), and then again accumulated over ten points.  The second time they go over ten, a notification is not sent out because one was previously sent out and so the second if statement evaluates to false.

I've tried adding an or statement to the original if statement to check and see if the student had previously received a notification and the date it was sent is before today.  However, I am not too skilled with datetime and am kinda unsure how to do this.  I also tried removing the if statement that checks if one was already sent out, but that causes multiple notifications to happen for a single event where a student has ten or more points.

notification_check.py:

```
def check_for_point_triggered():

def current_semester():
    return AcademicTerm.objects.filter(date_end__gte=timezone.now(),
                                       date_start__lte=timezone.now()
                                       ).order_by('date_end', '-date_start')[0]

emps_to_check = Employee.objects.that_have_active_points()

try:
    ten_pts_template = NotificationTemplate.objects.get(
        name="10 Points")
    signature = NotificationSignature.objects.get(
        name="AutoSignature")
except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
    raise CommandError(e)

for emp in emps_to_check:
    points = emp.discipline_points()


    # Check the 10 points template
    if points >= 10:
        if not emp.notificationrecord_set.filter(points__gte=10, semester=current_semester()):
            # Need to send an expiration notification
            notification = Notification(
                sender=User.objects.get(username="mailer"),
                title=ten_pts_template.title,
                template=ten_pts_template,
                signature=signature,
                date_created=timezone.now(),
                trigger='P'
            )
            notification.save()
            notification.employee_recepients.add(emp)
            notification.staff_recepients.add(*emp.supervisors())
            try:
                notification.staff_recepients.add(
                    User.objects.get(username='schaf1ka'))
            except Exception:
                print "Error adding user schaf1ka to 10 point email"

            # Now to create a record
            record = NotificationRecord(
                employee=emp,
                notification=notification,
                email_text=notification.build_emails()[0].body,
                points=points,
                semester=current_semester(),
                date_notified=timezone.now(),
            )
            record.save()

            # Now to create automatic dismissal
            EmployeeDismissal.objects.create(employee=emp,
                                             date_dismissed=datetime.today())
```

models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    """
    Deconstructed email parts allows for reconstruction.
    Record will be stored in NotificationRecord table.
    Contains methods to build EmailMessage classes.
    """
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, default="UREC Message", db_index=True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)

    # Recepients
    employee_recepients = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, blank=True)
    staff_recepients = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='staff_recepients', blank=True)
    emp_groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        EmploymentGroup, related_name='employee_groups', blank=True,
        verbose_name="Employee Groups")
    send_to_all_employees = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Email Pieces
    template = models.ForeignKey(NotificationTemplate, blank=True, null=True)
    signature = models.ForeignKey(NotificationSignature, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    perf_report = models.ForeignKey(PerformanceReport, blank=True, null=True)
    emp_cert = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeCertification, blank=True, null=True)
    trigger = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPES, null=True)

    # String of recepient names for recent notifications admin view
    def recepient_names(self):
        employees = ', '.join(
            [a.global_id for a in self.employee_recepients.all()])
        staff = ', '.join(
            [a.username for a in self.staff_recepients.all()])
        if staff:
            return staff + ", " + employees
        return employees

    recepient_names.short_description = "Recipients"

    def set_sent_flag(self):
        if not self.date_sent:
            a = self
            a.date_sent = timezone.now()
            a.save()

    # Returns a list of emails. Will only be 1 email if it has no template
    def build_emails(self):
        """
        Returns a list of EmailMessages. Will be 1 bcc'd EmailMessage
        if no template is found.
        """
        email_messages = []
        # Append employees in groups to employee recepients
        for group in self.emp_groups.all():
            emps = group.employees()
            for emp in emps:
                self.employee_recepients.add(emp)

        # Add all employees if checked
        if self.send_to_all_employees:
            for emp in Employee.objects.filter(category=Category.objects.get(name="Active")):
                self.employee_recepients.add(emp)

        if self.template:
            translated_template = Template(self.template.translate_tags())

            for person in self.employee_recepients.all():
                custom_body = translated_template.render(Context({"employee": person,
                    "pr": self.perf_report, "ec": self.emp_cert}))
                # Append body from form if it exists
                if self.body:
                    custom_body = custom_body + "\n\n" + self.body
                if self.signature:
                    custom_body = custom_body + "\n\n" + self.signature.body
                # Append custom email to email list

                message = EmailMessage(subject=self.template.title,
                                       to=[person.global_id + "@cmich.edu"],
                                       body=custom_body)

                # If only one employee recepient, cc all of the staff
                # recepients
                if len(self.employee_recepients.all()) == 1:
                    message.cc = [x.username + "@cmich.edu" for x in self.staff_recepients.all()]

                email_messages.append(message)

        # No template found
        if not self.template:
            custom_body = self.body
            if self.signature:
                custom_body = self.body + '\n\n' + self.signature.body

            email_messages.append(
                EmailMessage(subject=self.title, body=custom_body,
                             cc=[x.global_id + "@cmich.edu" for x in self.employee_recepients.all()]))

        return email_messages

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title + " " + self.date_created.strftime("%x %X"))


class NotificationRecordManager(models.Manager):

    def one_month_back(self):
        four_weeks = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=28)
        return self.model.objects.filter(date_created__gt=four_weeks)


class NotificationRecord(models.Model):
    """
    Constructed notification email to allow for duplicate searching.
    Contains resolved template tags.
    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    notification = models.ForeignKey(Notification)
    certification = models.ForeignKey(
        EmployeeCertification, blank=True, null=True)
    dismissal = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeDismissal, blank=True, null=True)
    discpoints = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeDiscipline, blank=True, null=True)
    email_text = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    semester = models.ForeignKey(AcademicTerm, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = NotificationRecordManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(unicode(self.employee) + unicode(self.date_created))
```

Comment: Apologies if this doesn't seem like an answer, but my first thought is that perhaps some code needs adding to reset/modify the 'notification has been sent' flag when points are deducted rather than trying to do it at this end. That way you might be able to simplify the logic for notifications and stick with your current setup

Comment: That's a really great idea, however this is project is in Django and so the deduction of points is actually taken care of in helm rather than in the code

Comment: Ah ok. Well I'll try to more directly answer the question then. Assuming then that 'timezone' is the one from Django.utils? If so, you have the [localdate function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localdate) which returns just the date from a datetime object taking into account the timezone settings. It will return a standard Python Date object which you can compare using the normal < and > operators - i.e. add a clause to the if statement which checks that the date of the notification is < localdate()

Comment: However might also be worth checking the filter values for emp.notificationrecord_set.filter - looking at the models.py snippet I see 'filter(date_created__gt=four_weeks)'. Different function but is that kind of filter perhaps also applicable to the emp.notificationrecord_set search?

Comment: Great thank you! The localdate solution appears to be working.  I believe that 'filter(date_created__gt=four_weeks)' is applicable to the emp.notificationrecord_set search